# Cant set buildFeatures databinding with Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am migrating to Kotlin dsl and I can't set buildFeatures property databinding any more. It is missing from AppExtension class. It is happening in dynamic feature module

Any suggestions?

Before in Groovy worked

```
android {
   buildFeatures {
     dataBinding = true 
   }
}
```

Kotlin is not working either the same syntax or

```
buildFeatures.dataBinding = true
```

Attaching some screenshots.

The error is

```
Unresolved reference: dataBinding
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a Studio bug. What version are you using? It definitely works, but either the project is bugged or it's from Android Studio. You can try to clear cache

Comment: using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 4

Comment: and AGP 4.2.1. I submitted a bug with Android gradle on G tracker but waiting to see if people have it working or not

Answer (score 1):

After submitting a ticket to Google the answer is to use
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193452960

```
android.dataBinding.isEnabled = true
```

Based on the dev reply marking it as deprecated is a bug and should not be thee case in kts.

From the ticket:

> Sorry for the mixed messages about build features, we realized that it made more sense to put the enable flag for features next to the feature itself. The plan is that the supported path will be:android.dataBinding.isEnabled = true
> Which works today in kts, but is currently incorrectly marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to upgrade your AGP.

Comment: I am using latest stable release

Comment: any version you are suggesting?